# Data Refresh for Entities in Power Apps Portal Programatically using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, powerapps

I am trying to write a programmatic approach using C# to automatically update the Entities on the Power Apps Portal.The data source for entities can be a simple excel sheet or a SQL DB. Can some one please guide me through the quick steps i need to follow to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft decided handling cache was quite difficult, so they just base refresh the cache after a period of time now.
That being said, it's plausible they still refresh the cache on publish of the entity like they used to.
You could test this easily by making a change to a record, publishing customisations for the entity and seeing if now the change is reflected in the portal.
If that works you could try a jamming in some code to programatically publish customisation's to an entity:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/customize-dev/publish-customizations